# What is the appropriate way to get the values of JSON_SEARCH results in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json

I have a JSON array like this:

```
[{"name": "test@test.com", ...}, {"name": "test2@test.com", ...}, {"name": "test@test.com", ...}, {"name": "blah blah", ...}, {"name": "+70000000", ...}]
```

I'm trying to get a string that will only contain e-mails. This has to be done within a select statement, if possible.

Something like this:

```
test@test.com, test2@test.com, test@test.com
```

Unique values would be even better.

I was able to convert result of JSON_SEARCH to this TEXT value:

```
'$[0].name', '$[1].name', '$[2].name'
```

with this code:

```
REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING  ']' from TRIM(LEADING '[' from JSON_SEARCH(accounts, 'all', '%@%'))),'"',"'")
```

But I can't use it as path arguments. What is the appropriate way to get the values of JSON_SEARCH results?

Here is the full code, that I tried to use:

```
select accounts
  ,JSON_EXTRACT(accounts, REPLACE(TRIM(TRAILING  ']' from TRIM(LEADING '[' from JSON_SEARCH(accounts, 'all', '%@%'))),'"',"'"))
from data
where 1 = 1
  and customer_id =1
```

MySQL v8 is used.

Comment: You want solution in code or specifically in SQL? I would be much easier to describe the solution in objects

Comment: I could filter this JSON later in python, but I was wondering if it's possible to do this operation just with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 8.0 extended JSON support with a nice function called `JSON_TABLE()`, that can be used to unnest JSON arrays.

Here is a solution that generates one row for each item that appears in the array:

```
select d.id, t.*
from 
    data d,
    json_table(d.accounts, '$[*]' columns(idx for ordinality, name varchar(50) path '$.name')) t
order by d.id, t.idx
```

This yields:

```
id | idx | name          
-: | --: | :-------------
 1 |   1 | test@test.com 
 1 |   2 | test2@test.com
 1 |   3 | test@test.com 
 1 |   4 | blah blah     
 1 |   5 | +70000000
```

You can then filter and aggregate to get the result that you expect:

```
select d.id, group_concat(t.name order by t.idx) names 
from 
    data d,
    json_table(d.accounts, '$[*]' columns(idx for ordinality, name varchar(50) path '$.name')) t
where t.name like '%@%'
group by id
```

```
id | names                                     
-: | :-----------------------------------------
 1 | test@test.com,test2@test.com,test@test.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in code - like this (c# pseudo-code)

```
using Newton.Soft
...

var myList = JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<YourEntity>>(jsonStringYouHave);
var emails = myList.Select(x=>x.Email).Distinct();
var emailsInString = emails.Join(',');
```

Wham! :o)

notice this algorithm is much simpler to describe in OOP?

Comment: I guess you thought of the Python version of my code. Good. As long as the job gets done.